# DownloadManager Notification no showing in android 13

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-13

```
  val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://xxx.xx"))
            val filename = "update" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            val dir: String = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/"
            val file = File("$dir$filename.apk")
            request.setTitle("dm-test")
            request.setDescription("downing...")
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive")
            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))
            downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

this code working in android api<33 is no problem, in android api=33 Notification no working

Comment: Starting from Android 13 you must have permission to show notifications. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Comment: I have applied for this permission
```
when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ) -> {
                Log.i("checkPermission","success")
            }
            else -> {
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        }
```

Comment: @midai Note that for permission requests to work, you need to make sure you also have those permissions registered in the manifest. Check that you registered the required permissions in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can try once

request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

May be it can work

Comment: This is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setVisibleInDownloadsUi(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

If your app target OS is android 13 you need to request notification permission from the user.

You can refer the link below,

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission